# TSQL - First and last number in range

Tags: t-sql, range

I have table with:
1
2
3
4
5
6
9
10
11
12 
and I need to receive:
1-6
9-12
How I can do that?
I need to see that I have two or more range of number i table and that from 1 to 6 and from 9 to 12.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
    CONCAT(MIN(A.b), '-', max(A.b))
FROM
(
    SELECT
        *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY b) RowId
    FROM
        (VALUES (1), (2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12)) a(b)
    --WHERE
        --(a.b >= 1 AND a.b <= 6) OR
        --(a.b >= 9 AND a.b <= 12) 
) A
GROUP BY
    A.b - A.RowId
```

Comment: No no, I need to see that in table are two range of number and thats from 1 to 6 and from 9 to 12.

Comment: Maybe I wrong explain. I want to see first and last number in row without break. Now I want to see that first number its 1 and last in that range are 6, next range are from 9 to 12. But next time it will be other numbers and I need range from them.

Comment: How do you range?

Comment: I find MIN(number) and need to see which it's last number in uninteruppted row. On example if number are 4, 5, 6, 8, 9 then MIN(number) = 4 and last in row are 6, then next min are 8 and last 9. And I want to receive 2 row: 4-6, 8-9

Comment: that's correct result, but not procedure. In FROM need to be (select number from table) and that's not problem. Problem are in WHERE when I don't want statis 1-6 and 9-12, I want that SELECT recognized when range are end and when starts new range.

Comment: Remove `WHERE` then